# Spring Data + Mongo list nested complex type using id as attribute in mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

How can I work with complex types in Spring Data + Mongo?

Like:

```
class Person {

    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
    //What can I do?
    Address address
    //OR
    String adressId;
}
```

How can I build this object for server side use?

I want to use adressId, but I don't know how to proceed when I need to use the address within some method.

For example:

```
void doWithPerson(Person person){

    System.out.println(person.getAdress());//this doesn't exist with adressId
}
```

Edit:

I want the mongo object as:

```
{
  id: 1
  name: 'Test'
  addressId: 1//not the complext object
}
```

and in addressCollection:

```
{
  id: 1
  address: 'Some info'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@DBRef` annotation to store reference of another object into your class object, e.g.:

```
@DBRef(lazy = true)
Address address;
```

This way, you can find the `Person` with particular address id. You can also retrieve `Address` objects independently by using `mongo repository` for `Address` class.

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html) is the documentation.

Comment: But, my mongo object will be `{ id: '1', name: 'Name', adressId: '1' }` or  `{ id: '1', name: 'Name', adress: {//object} }`

Comment: With `@DBef`, your mongo object will be `{id : 1, address : {$ref : address, $id : addressId}}`

Comment: Is the same for collections? There is some way to clean this {$ref ... object?

Comment: You don't need to worry about it, spring data will take care of it for you. And yes, it's already clean as it just stores the id reference and not the whole object.